# What’s difference between `cat <file` with `cat file`?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Those look same. Maybe I’m misunderstaning about `<` operator.

Why those two commands give same results?

Comment: suggest to go through http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

Answer (score 5):

With `cat < file`, `cat` reads from its standard input; the shell opens the file and connects the file handle to `cat`. With `cat file`, `cat` itself opens the file without any shell involvement. The end result is indeed the same for both: `cat` reads the contents of `file` and outputs them to standard output.

Comment: Nice and precise, although I would bet that this must have been asked and answered here before.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is specific to the behavior of the `cat` command; some other commands behave the same way.