# Getting file handle as an argument

Tags: c++, bash, filehandle

In bash redirection, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43624403/766330) and got an answer as follows.

> With `cat < file`, `cat` reads from its standard input; the shell opens the file and connects the file handle to `cat`

Now, I’m curious how this is possible. I mean, how a program(implemented by C or C++ like that) get a file handle as an argument. I knew only characters(eg. `char* argc[]`) were possible as arguments.

Comment: It does not do this via the command line arguments.  It changes where `stdin` gets its input when your process runs.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really get it as an argument (at least not a command line argument).

When a process is started (on a UNIX-like system) it has three standard streams opened: standard input, standard output, and standard error. If you don't redirect anything, standard input will come from the keyboard, and both standard output and standard error will go to the screen (connected via some devices, such as in `/dev`).

When you redirect standard a stream (input, output or error) the shell opens a handle to that file, and then does the manipulation necessary to set it as the specified standard stream for the child--for example, on a system that uses `fork`, it can use `dup2` to set its own standard handle to the specified file, then fork the child process, and then (in the parent) restore its standard stream (that's not the only possible way to handle it, just one possibility).

Answer (score 1):

`<` and `file` are *not* arguments.

`<` (and similarly `>`, `>>`, and `|` are *redirection symbols* and their behavior is embedded directly in `bash` (and other shells, too).

The *redirection* means that instead of the *standard input / output* (keyboard and monitor) the program read / write from / to a *file* (`<`, `>`, and `>>`), or - in the case of `|` - the output of the left program is passed as input to the right program.

(It supposes that corresponding program - as `cat` in your case - *is programmed to read / writes from standard input / output*. For a programmer it is a very convenient way as he / she need not be concerned with files and their handlers.)

Answer (score 1):

The `<` character means that the input stream is redirected from `stdin` to `file`. The program does not get the file handle as an argument but the `stdin` handle gets replaced by handle to `file` provided in the command line. See the description of [Redirection on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing))